# How to resolve the MappingException?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I received the following exception:

> org.json4s.package$MappingException: Classes defined in method bodies
>   are not supported.

That happens when executing the following route:

```
path(resourceAPI / "locatebinarycontent") {
  parameters('resourceid, 'contentid) { (resourceId, contentId) =>
    complete {
      val path = getPathToBinaryFile(resourceId, contentId)
      getFromFile(path)
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect it is due to introducing a brand new utility class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule


object JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)

  def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
  }

  def toList[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]) = fromJson[List[Metadata]](json)

  def toResource[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]) = fromJson[Resource](json)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
}
```

I wonder how to resolve such an Exception?

Comment: Remove the wrapping `complete` because `getFromFile` should be enough. `complete` is used to generate a response from the expression you give to it. Here you just want to return a file, so you can use the `getFromFile(path)` without anything else.